# Frameless flash player needed

Tags: flash, transparent, flvplayer

i need a flv player like in [this](http://www.vijital.com/) site(video of woman at the bottom left). I could not find a free one, do u know any free flash player that i can play flv videos in a frameless player like in this site? I have a transparent flv movie.

Comment: Hint: HTML5 video is a much better alternative.

Comment: yes i know, but probably the visitors of the site wont have an html5 supported browser unfortunatly. Anyway thanks for the hint

Comment: Not really. The only major browser that doesn't support HTML5 video is Internet Explorer before version 9. Outside of America and China, Internet Explorer is usually no longer the majority browser, especially in some parts of Europe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here I found and used for my purpose.[Creating a SWF File from the FLV File](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=8&cid=8F805)